# Django x Postgres Migrate and Migration error

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I get this error anytime i run makemigrations:

```
/home/azeez/bendownselect/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py:160: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

and i get this error if i run migrate:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

this is my db config:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env("POSTGRES_DB"),
        'USER': env("POSTGRES_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': env("POSTGRES_HOST"),
        'PORT': env("POSTGRES_PORT"),  
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I can't see what your database configuration is since it's hidden behind environment variables so it's hard to say for sure. But it seems like the HOST value is incorrect, and maybe even unspecified so it's using a default. The HOST value needs to be the location of the database. This can be `postgres` if you're running a docker container that connects to postgres as a docker service, but if you're running a production build on a hosting platform like GCP you'll need the IP address of the database instance.

Comment: My host is from the postgres service on railway.app. and I've tried locally still same results.

Comment: The variables available in railway are listed here https://docs.railway.app/guides/postgresql and you can see how they should be used in database setup here https://dev.to/dennisivy11/easiest-django-postgres-connection-ever-with-railway-11h6

Comment: The error is not coming from the railway or db settings

Comment: Right, but the error is Django telling you that it can't connect to a database using the host provided. You need to configure Django to use the proper host, using the environment variables provided by railway